# sorting of python dict, first by value then by key

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I want to sort a dict, first by the value and then by the key. The key being a string.

Example,

```
>>> words = {'fall':4, 'down':4, 'was':3, 'a':3, 'zebra':2, 'bitter':1, 'betty':1}
>>> sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True)
[('fall', 4), ('down', 4), ('was', 3), ('a', 3), ('zebra', 2), ('bitter', 1), ('betty', 1)]
```

As you can see above, the dict is getting sorted by value but not by the key.

Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to point out that I wanted the values to get sorted top to down and the key bottom to top.

Comment: It looks sorted to me - 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1. If values are equal they are sorted by the key. Everything is in reversed order, because of the `reverse=True`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: `but not by the key` yes it is. what else would you have?

Comment: What I forgot to write was that I wanted the keys to be sorted the other way, that is, ascending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Take advantage of the fact that the values are numbers.

```
from operator import itemgetter

words = {'fall':4, 'down':4, 'was':3, 'a':3, 'zebra':2, 'bitter':1, 'betty':1}
sorted_words = [v for v in sorted(words.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (-v, k))]
print(sorted_words)
```

Output:

```
[('down', 4), ('fall', 4), ('a', 3), ('was', 3), ('zebra', 2), ('betty', 1), ('bitter', 1)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work in the general case(when `-` is not defined for the object or has different meaning).

Comment: This is right, but in his case his values are numbers, so it works for the OP

Comment: Folowing also works: sorted(words.iteritems(), key=lambda(k,v): (-v,k))